# Question about Hierarchical data

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data

I am reading the following article, http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database/2 about"Storing Hierarchical Data in a Database".

This is talking about these structures. http://sitepointstatic.com/graphics/sitepoint_numbering.gif and http://sitepointstatic.com/graphics/table02.gif

I don't understand the following passages. What do these mean.

***"Each time you start with the children of a node, you add the right value of that node to the stack."***

and

***"When you're finished displaying a node, you remove its right value from the stack. If you count the elements in the stack, you'll get the level of the current node."***

I am hoping someone explains these in a simpler way if possible.

> To show the tree structure, children
>   should be indented slightly more than
>   their parent. We can do this by
>   keeping a stack of right values. Each
>   time you start with the children of a
>   node, you add the right value of that
>   node to the stack. You know that all
>   children of that node have a right
>   value that is less than the right
>   value of the parent, so by comparing
>   the right value of the current node
>   with the last right node in the stack,
>   you can see if you're still displaying
>   the children of that parent. When
>   you're finished displaying a node, you
>   remove its right value from the stack.
>   If you count the elements in the
>   stack, you'll get the level of the
>   current node.

Comment: The phrase 'nested sets' is not mentioned in that article, which is a shame because that's the method it is describing. If you try googling for "Nested Sets" you will find a lot more information about it.

Comment: What specifically don't you understand? Do you know what a 'stack' is? If you replace the word 'stack' with 'list' does it make sense to you now?

Comment: "you add the right value of that node to the stack" If I pick up "Red" which is (3, 6). Where do I add 6 to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're trying to come up with a way to use Nested Sets for indenting data by the level in the tree.

```
Food (1,12)
|
+--Fruit (2,11)
  |
  +--Red (3,6)
  | |
  | +--Cherry (4,5)
  |
  +--Yellow (7,10)
    |
    +--Banana (8,9)
```

So as you fetch the rows, you push the `rgt` number onto the end of an array:

```
$right[] = $row['rgt'];
```

This array grows as you process children and subchildren.  For example, by the time we get to "Cherry" the array looks like this:

```
array(11, 6, 5)
```

As long as we're descending down a branch of the tree, the `rgt` values in this should be getting less, because a child's `rgt` value is always less than its parent's `rgt` value.

The next row we process is "Yellow" which has a `rgt` value of 10.  This value 10 is *greater* than the last value in the array, which means we're not descending down one branch anymore, we're on a different branch.  We need to pop numbers out of the array until 10 is no longer greater than the last number in the array.

```
array(11, 6) // 10 is still greater than 6
array(11)    // 10 is not greater than 11, so stop
```

Now we know that the array contains only ancestors of our current row "Yellow".

The level in the tree is always equal to the number of elements in that array.